# What is the best BTC miner for intel HD 4000 card?

Tags: bitcoind, cgminer, mining-software, bfgminer

Right now I am using GUIminer(and some guides said not to use it), it gets ~80Mhash/s but this miner is laggy, sometimes disconnects without a reason, and it is slow... So I would like to use cgminer, but it doesn't find Intel hd card...

so how do I use cgminer with Intel HD 4000 integrated card, so it could mine? Or what miner would you suggest?

NOTE: this is a question by a guy who is working with BTC for like 1h lol AND I don't want to receive answers who say this is stupid or ineffective.. or it's Impossible.

The question is HOW would You do this with the restrictions of an integrated video card? lets say for theoretical learning purposes, NOT TO MAKE MONEY! I just wanna see if I can make it work.

Or maybe I should use BFGMiner if he would work better(or at all) with Intel integrated HD 4000 card?
thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you should be using cgminer to mine a GPU coin with your GPU :). Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you're going to get bored real quick when your miner returns 2 cents for the week.

I recommend mining Litecoin with your GPU. Convert to bitcoin on BTC-e.com if thats your favorite. Its practically the same challenge/experience that you're working at, but you'll at least see some progress. Good luck!